# Alsa and alsactl: init, store and default configuration of control file

Tags: linux-kernel, audio, alsa

The target kernel is: 2.6.35.14 (old) and its running on an embedded platform and the codec is a wm8753.

I am trying to understand how the alsactl system works. I found a file asound.play @ etc/alsa and this is the configuration file the man pages refer to. I am not sure why mine is called asound.play instead of asound.state but running:

```
#alsactl init
#alsactl -f /etc/alsa/asound.play store
```

will default the asound.play file. With the customized version sound works but it doesn't with the default configuration. Here is an excerpt from the asound.play file for a default configuration and the custom configuration. Keep in mind this is just one control block of 85:

Default:

```
control.1 {
        comment.access 'read write'
        comment.type INTEGER
        comment.count 2
        comment.range '0 - 255'
        comment.dbmin -12750
        comment.dbmax 0
        iface MIXER
        name 'PCM Volume'
        value.0 215
        value.1 215
    }
```

custom:

```
control.1 {
        comment.access 'read write'
        comment.type INTEGER
        comment.count 2
        comment.range '0 - 255'
        iface MIXER
        name 'PCM Volume'
        value.0 250
        value.1 250
    }
```

It isn't obvious to me how the person who originally customized the file knew that she/he needed to get rid of comment.dbmin and dbmax. So how might one go about figuring out how they should be customizing this file so that sound works? Guess and check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that the `dbmin`/`dbmax` comments are missing because that file was generated with an older version of the driver that did not yet have dB information.
Anyway, comments are ignored by `alsactl restore`, so this does not matter.

The `iface` and `name` entries identify a mixer control; the `value` values specify the value(s) of that control.

To get the sound to work, you have to know how these mixer controls affect the hardware. Obviously, whoever created those customized settings did know.

Comment: So anything that says comment.(stuff) is insignificant? All I need to worry about is: iface, name, value.0 and value.1? Do you know off hand if there is somewhere I can go to learn how these mixer controls effect the hardware?

Comment: Yes. Yes. That would be the documentation of your embedded platform.